# Connect servers running on two ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, microservices

I'm a big newbie when it comes to JS and web apps.
I have two servers running on my computer on two different ports (5000 and 5001). The 5000 server provides a route that needs to communicate with the server on port 5001, and I can't seem to make that work.

I'm using express.js and xhr2 for the HTTP requests. There seem to be a problem with my url. Am I not supposed to look for the port at the 0.0.0.0 address ? (I have tried using the localhost one as well and it's not working).

You can find below an example of such a route. Thanks for your help !

```
app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
   var url = "0.0.0.0:5001/user"
   var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2')
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", url, true);
   console.log(url)
   xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
           if (xhr.status == 200) {
               res.status(200).send(xhr.responseText)
           }
       });
   xhr.send();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try `localhost:port` or `127.0.0.1:port`, maybe that works

edit: yea you forgot the schema, try `"http://localhost:5001/user"` or the same with https instead. (credit @Heiko Theiße)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried both of these yes, but somehow it doesn't work. I can't figure out what's the issue.

Comment: The schema (http or https) is missing, try `url = "http://localhost:5001/user";`